# cURL vs WP_Http for safety?

Tags: http-api

when it comes to cross domain request for personal information such as user information it must be done on the back-ed for safety reasons. I'm am new to cURL but it has been pointed out to not use it for WP development so instead I am using the inbuilt WP_Http in wordpress. I just want to know is it safe to do so because this method is sending information through the front end, so is there a safer method to do so?

Comment: Currently, WP HTTP API uses cURL if possible; it not it uses default PHP functions for HTTP requests. WP HTTP API is server-side code, I can not imagine how HTTP sends information from the fornt end. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WP_Http` class is essentially a wrapper for cURL in the same way that `wpdb` is essentially a wrapper for `mysqli`.  As such, implemented properly, using cURL directly is exactly as safe as using `WP_Http` (since `WP_Http` uses cURL to make the requests).

That said, implementing cURL functions optimally isn't the easiest thing in the world to do.  What makes `WP_Http` so useful is that it takes over a lot of the heavy lifting for you e.g. standardizing error handling, request structures, etc.  It also gives you a suite of useful helper functions that make requesting specific things from cURL requests much simpler.

Ideally, if you are making a lot of cURL requests you would be writing a suite of functions yourself so that you don't have to have duplicate code everywhere, `WP_Http` just does it for you.

That is all just a long way of saying that `WP_Http` doesn't request information through the frontend.  If it did then it would be doing something like an ajax call which, as you allude to, generally shouldn't (and in many browsers can't) be used for cross-domain requests.