# How do I start using an external API and PHP for a WordPress.org page?

Tags: php, api

I have created some reports for some web pages that use JavaScript HTTP Requests to retrieve some data from an API.
I would like to use the reports on some WordPress pages.
I have done a lot of searching and reading.
I am a complete beginner at customizing a WordPress page.
While I don't mind experimenting, I would rather get some guidance for how to proceed.

The options appear to be:

- Use a plugin to allow JavaScript on a WordPress page.
- Use PHP to call the API, and then use PHP to create the HTML to display the data returned returned from the API.

I think the second one would be better because learning to use PHP on a WordPress page would allow for more options in the future.

I have worked in software development. I have done some programming on my own in JavaScript and Python3. I am currently going through some courses at Lynda.com to learn PHP. I am confident that I can pick it up or find what I need online to create the code I need.

I have found this plug-in:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-everywhere/
It appears to allow me to use PHP on a WordPress page.

I also found this:
WordPress has the HTTP API.
https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

There are linked pages that explain how to make a request and get a response code and data:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_response_code
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

I have no problem understanding this because I did the web pages using JavaScript to get API data.

I just don't understand how to start using it. Is this a plugin? I don't think so. I think it is built-in code that I can just use.

So, can I just use the GET and Response Code functions in this reference in my PHP code once I have installed that first plug-in? (Did I mention that I am a complete beginner with customizing a WordPress page?)

I have found a number of websites explaining how to install a plug-in.
I have found some websites explaining how to use the WP HTTP API.
But, I need an even more basic explanation as to how to start with the WP HTTP API, and how to combine all of this. I haven't found that anywhere.

My next steps appear to be:

1. Install that plug-in (php-everywhere).
   Write some simple PHP code to create some HTML to test it on a test page.
2. Write a simple API call using the GET and Response Code functions from the Codex pages.
   Once I get some data successfully returned, I can then write more PHP code to incorporate the returned data. 
   (I can use the web pages written in JavaScript as a guide to write the PHP to display the data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gina, and welcome!

I'm fairly new to the craft too, but I would love to share what I wish I knew from the very beginning.

> Install that plug-in (php-everywhere). Write some simple PHP code to
>   create some HTML to test it on a test page

When it comes to that I think it's better to just dig into the themes that produce the front-end. So here's some resources for you to read.

1. Understanding the WordPress themes. Here's a link to the [Theme
   Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/). This will help you get around any theme, including the
   ones that come with every installation of WordPress;
2. making and editing a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). I think editing a child theme
   is easier than creating one from scratch because one can just go back to the 
   parent theme and copy an original file if one made a mess in his child 
   theme' code;
3. another thing that I think will be very helpful and will eliminate
   the need of using the `php-everywhere` plugin is the knowledge of how
   to make a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). This will allow you to make a blank
   page that you can fill with whatever you want;
4. of Course, if you get through the entire handbook you might want to
   start your own theme and there's a nice tool for that one too —
   [_s](https://underscores.me/) gives you a barebones theme that you can upgrade.

> Write a simple API call using the GET and Response Code functions from
>   the Codex pages. Once I get some data successfully returned, I can
>   then write more PHP code to incorporate the returned data. (I can use
>   the web pages written in JavaScript as a guide to write the PHP to
>   display the data.)

Once you have a `child theme` with your own `page template` you can write in it whatever you fancy. Some functions are better suited for the function.php file, but that, I think, will come with the practice and the knowledge.

Hope I helped, good luck!

Comment: So, if I learn themes/child themes, I won't need that php-everywhere plug-in. Is that correct? I can use PHP on a WP page. But, will that require me to install/use cURL for an API request? Or, can I just use the WordPress HTTP API ?

Comment: Hmm...OK...I found this. It appears that the WordPress HTTP API uses cURL, and could make things simpler: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185251/curl-vs-wp-http-for-safety

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks to your information, I did some reading and searching, and  found this video about how to add PHP to a WP theme. So, now I am going to read the pages you linked more thoroughly to learn about Themes, Child Themes and page templates. I want a good understanding of what I am doing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-ivr_ECyXY

Comment: @Gina I'm very glad to hear that! :) I'm not very familiar with the HTTP requests since I do mostly theme based front-end and I use pretty much only WordPress' functions, but I think one can hook some JavaScript and do some AJAX requests too. There's also jQuery that comes with the WP installation.

Comment: You gave me a clear path to find out what I needed to do! Here is one page that helped me understand JavaScript API requests. The code examples are very good: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/